# Bootstrap modals sequencing with fade effect, causing scroll to break

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap 3.3.6 and i am kind of new to it and Web programming in general.

There are two modals say A and B, both defined to be loaded and unloaded with fade effect. Now, i am supposed load A and B one after another, i.e.

> - A shows
> - *Do some work*
> - A hides
> - B shows
> - *Do some work*
> - B hides

Now, when the sequence

> A hides,
>   B shows

happens, it causes scroll function on the modal to break. Upon, tinkering a bit, i found that is happening because of the "fade" effect. The call to show the B is happening before A got hidden.

As a solution i had two approaches.

1. Turn off the fade effect
2. Show B when event 'hidden.bs.modal' happen.

Following (2), it kind of hardwire the Launching of B whenever A gets hidden, breaking sequencing of A with other modals.

So, i have two questions

1. What is the proper way to Sequence two modals appearance and disappearance with fade effect?
2. How i can add a handle to an event, which is supposed execute only once?

Answer (score 0):

for 2nd question, got the following solution..

instead of using

```
$("").on("",function())
```

we can use

```
$("").one("",function())
```

to launch the handle only once.

Also, i was curious, what could be the way to remove an handle once associated with ".on".